# How to invoke a method in java using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

How can I invoke a method with parameters using reflection ?

I want to specify the values of those parameters.

Comment: Why is there a tag `eclipse-plugin`?

Comment: I removed the `eclipse-plugin` tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a simple example of invoking a method using reflection involving primitives.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class ReflectionExample {
    public int test(int i) {
        return i + 1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Method testMethod = ReflectionExample.class.getMethod("test", int.class);
        int result = (Integer) testMethod.invoke(new ReflectionExample(), 100);
        System.out.println(result); // 101
    }
}
```

To be robust, you should catch and handle all checked reflection-related exceptions `NoSuchMethodException`, `IllegalAccessException`, `InvocationTargetException`.

Answer (score 5):

To call a class method using reflection is very simple.
You need to create a class and generate method in it. like as follows.

```
package reflectionpackage;

public class My {
    public My() {
    }

    public void myReflectionMethod() {
        System.out.println("My Reflection Method called");
    }
}
```

and call this method in another class using reflection.

```
package reflectionpackage; 
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; 
import java.lang.reflect.Method; 

public class ReflectionClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Class c=Class.forName("reflectionpackage.My");
        Method m=c.getDeclaredMethod("myReflectionMethod");
        Object t = c.newInstance();
        Object o= m.invoke(t);       
    } 
}
```

[Find more details  here](http://compilr.org/java/call-class-method-using-reflection/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getClass](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) in any Object to discover its class.  Then you can use [getMethods](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()) to discover all the available methods.  Once you have the correct method you can call [invoke](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object[])) with any number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest way I know of, it needs to be surrounded with try & catch:

Method m = .class.getDeclaredMethod("", arg_1.class, arg_2.class, ... arg_n.class);
  result = () m.invoke(null,(Object) arg_1, (Object) arg_2 ... (Object) arg_n);

this is for invoking a static method, if you want to invoke a non static method, you need to replace the first argument of m.invoke() from null to the object the underlying method is invoked from.

don't forget to add an import to java.lang.reflect.*;

Comment: what if i am using primitives

Comment: @Shuky: why casting the arguments to Object?

Comment: @Seteven, Carlos Heuberger: the casting is not required, I just meant they cannot be primitives (instead of int, use Integer, etc)