# Dynamically generate method arguments

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I am trying to call `newInstance` method of `java.lang.reflect.Constructor` class in order to create an object based on constructor received.
I need to generate dynamic call in **class B**

```
class A
{
    void method()
    {
        ABC abc = new ABC(arg1,arg2);
        Constructor c = Class.forName("someClass").getConstructor(ABC.class);
        Object o = B.getObject(c,abc);
        Object 
        //do something
    }

}
class B
{
    public static Object getObject(Constructor c, Object... args)
    {
        //how to create dynamic call here???
        c.newInstance(args[0],args[1],...,args[args.length-1]);
    }
}
class someClass
{
    someClass(ABC abc)
    {
        //do something
    }
    someClass(ABC abc, int a)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I cannot modify someClass whatsoever. (Actually someClass is just an example. I am calling 10-15 different calsses, so modifying is not an option. Plus, I need to make class B generic)

Comment: Here's a [simple question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2407242/778118) that shows how to invoke a method using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array as a `...` parameter:

```
c.newInstance(args)
```

Comment: this won't work since `newInstance` method assumes that the constructor has only 1 argument viz. `Object[]`

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: You sure? It seems to work when I try it; I'll try some more and either show you a demonstration it works or find out you're right.

Comment: It was giving `IllegalArgumentException` when I tried. Do show me a demo if it works for you

Comment: I hope you realize that my issue is not that I cannot set array as a parameter rather I need to send all array elements as different arguments

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: Take a look at the following: http://ideone.com/lDCHob

Comment: It really works, but I am now puzzled : what if the constructor itself needs an Object[] ? see: http://ideone.com/eVuqLy

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: Then you wrap it in *another* array - `c.newInstance(new Object[] {array})` - or cast it to `Object` so the compiler wraps it in another array for you - `c.newInstance((Object) array)`.