# How to invoke a Java class of another Jar file?

Tags: java, reflection, jar, invoke

I would like to receive the results dynamically invoke a class in another jar.

For example,

'A' directory in a file named A.jar.

'B' directory in a file named B.jar.

I want to dynamically invoke a class of A.jar file to B.jar file.

This is the main class of A.jar file.

Socket and RMI are not considered because the message exchange technology.

**Main Class (B.jar)**

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //It dynamically creates an object of a Message Class in A.jar.
    //And it invoke the getMessage function.
    //And Save the return value.

}}
```

**Message Class (A.jar)**

```
public class message{
    public String getMessage(){ 

       return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Comment: By `dynamically`, you mean by the class name as a String? Can we assume that `A.jar` is on the classpath?

Comment: Yes. It is to invoke the class of A.jar by class name(string).

Comment: You need a combination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886266/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-name-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407071/how-to-invoke-a-method-in-java-using-reflection

Comment: Is it possible to access any class in another jar file?

Comment: It is no problem to invoke the class as a String.
I want to know, How to dynamically invoke a class in another jar file

Answer (score 9):

First, you need to dynamically create an instance of the given class:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("message");
Object messageObj = clazz.newInstance();
```

This assumes that the `.jar` file which contains the `message` class is on the `classpath` so that the Java runtime is able to find it. Otherwise, you need to manually load the jar file through a class loader, e.g. like in [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime). Assumed that your `A.jar` file which contains the `message` class is located at `c:\temp\A.jar`, you can use something like

```
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (
        new URL[] {new URL("file:///c:/temp/A.jar")}, main.class.getClassLoader());
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("message", true, child);
```

to load the jar file and load the message class from it.

In both cases, you can then retrieve the method from the class and invoke it on the created instance:

```
Method getMessage = clazz.getMethod("getMessage");
String result = (String) getMessage.invoke(messageObj);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can i invoke  a class in another jar file?

Comment: As long as the other jar file is on the classpath, the above approach works. Otherwise, you need to dynamically load the jar file at runtime through a class loader.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach the given answer. where can i find a good pratical example.

Comment: I am still not clear about your actual issue - is your `A.jar` file on your classpath or not? If so, you can instantiate any public class from `A.jar` through `Class.forName`. Otherwise, you need to load `A.jar` through a class loader.

Comment: What I want, I want to dynamically invoke the another jar file, regardless of the classpath.

Comment: See my updated answer. To be pedantic, you can not invoke a jar file - you can only invoke methods from classes contained in a jar file.