# How can I access non public fields of non public class in other package?

Tags: java

How can I access non public fields of non public class in other package?

I have below non public class and I want to call getString from a class in other package. How do I do that?

```
class ABC{
   String getString(){
     return "ABC"
   }
}
```

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/java/how-to-access-all-private-fields-methods-and-constructors-using-java-reflection-with-example

Comment: You don't. There must be a reason why a field or an attribute is privae. However if you really want, take a look at Java Reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407071/how-to-invoke-a-method-in-java-using-reflection

Comment: Possibly related: [How to call a private method from outside a java class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11282265)

Answer (score 0):

This is what we call `access-level` in Java.

The documentation is actually pretty great and you can find it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).
See the table below (Copied from documentation).

- **modifier** -> It refers to `public`, `private`, `<no modiefier>` and `protected`.
- **scope** -> It refers to where you are trying to *access* a field from (e.g. `class`, `subclass`, etc..)
- **Y**     -> Indicates that a field can be accessed from specific scope.
- **N**     -> Indicates that a field can not be accessed from specific scope.

### Access Levels

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World |
|-------------|-------|---------|----------|-------|
| public      |   Y   |    Y    |    Y     |   Y   |
|-------------|-------|---------|----------|-------|
| protected   |   Y   |    Y    |    Y     |   N   |
|-------------|-------|---------|----------|-------|
| no modifier |   Y   |    Y    |    N     |   N   |
|-------------|-------|---------|----------|-------|
| private     |   Y   |    N    |    N     |   N   |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

> **It's actually a pretty interesting fact, that by adding no modifier
>   your code is actually more secure (isolated from the 'world') than with the `protected` modifier.**

To make a class (or a method) hidden from the rest of the world, apart from its own package, you give it no modifier. Like I showcase below with `class ABC`.

One possible solution, is to create another class, in that same package that can access only the fields you want the rest of the world to see.

```
package myPackage;

class ABC{
//implementation
}
```

```
package myPackage;

public class XYZ{

    /**
    *@return This method will invoke the getString() method in class ABC
    */
    public String getString(){
        return ABC.getString();//supposing that getString() is static
    }
}
```

```
package different_package;

import myPackage.*;

public class Main{

    //You could also do: 'myPackage.XYZ <variable name>'
    XYZ xyzInstance= new XYZ();

    /*some code*/

    // Accesses the method you want
    xyzInstance.getString();
}
```