# I have a Set<Class<? extends SomeClass>> and I'd like to call method from SomeClass class

Tags: java, generics, casting, java-stream

I have created a Set of classes which implements a certain interface using Reflections
like that:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.project.cookies");
Set<Class<? extends Cookie>> setOfCookies = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Cookie.class);
```

Now for all cookie i want to bake it eg.:

```
setOfCookies.stream().forEach(cookie -> cookie.bake());
```

When I call

```
cookie.getName()
```

I get:

```
com.project.cookies.Brownie
```

`Brownie` class implements the interface `Cookie` and has a method `bake()`.

I've tried to cast *cookie* element of type `Class<? extends Cookie>` into `Cookie` or `Brownie`, but I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Class to com.project.cookies.Cookie
```

I've also tried

```
cookie.getSuperclass().getConstructor(Cookie.class).newInstance()
```

but ite gives me some weird type `capture of ? super capture of ? extends Cookie` and i cannot call method on it.

**My question is how can I access `bake()` method having a `<Class<? extends Cookie>`?**

Comment: `Class<Cookie>` and `Cookie` is not the same. Instance of `Class<Cookie>` holds metadata *about Cookie* type. You can think of it as paper on which we have written list all fields, methods, constructors, etc. belonging to Cookie type. BUT IT IS NOT `Cookie` itself (you can't eat that paper and expect same results as eating proper Cookie). It looks like you want to *use* `Class<Cookie>` to call `bake()` method, but [while it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2407071) it sill *require an instance of Cookie/Brownie* on which that method will be called.

Comment: Your `setOfCookies` is not really a set of cookies. More like a `setOfCookieRecipes`

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo, one of the answer in the topic you mentioned  helped me.
The code below did the job:
Class clazz = Class.forName(cookie.getName());
            Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("bake");
            Object obj = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            method.invoke(obj);